# How i can keep the history of my navigation after a memory warning?

Tags: ios, three20

In my app I have a viewcontroller which throwing an `UIImagePickerController` that produces a `memory warning`. After many research I don't have found a solution to prevent this warning.

The problem is: When my app receives a `memory warning` the history of the navigation seems to be lost and when the user presses the back button, my app starts the first controller. (like when my app starts)

How i can keep the history of my navigation after a `memory warning`?
Or better how i can remove this `memory warning` with the `UIImagePickerController`? (I tried a lot of solutions found in stackoverflow.com and google.com)

An other solution for me is to prevent the `memory warning` to release all data of my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you with the memory warning without looking at the code but it seems like TTNavigator sends you back to the first view controller in the stack because it can't persist the others.

Are you inheriting from TTViewController?  If not you should try that.  Secondly if you're still having problems after inheriting from TTViewController look into implementing the following methods in your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)persistView:(NSMutableDictionary*)state {
  // Save important state information into the state dictionary
  // provided to you and return yes to tell TTNavigator to persist
  // this view controller
  return YES;
}

- (void)restoreView:(NSDictionary*)state {
  // Read the values you saved in state and restore your view
  // controller's state
}
```

Those methods are defined in UIViewControllerAdditions.h in the Three20UI project.  Hope that helps.